# Why using instance variables takes more memory compare to local variables in LeetCode?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I was trying to solve a graph problem using DFS on LeetCode. It turned out that using instance variables takes more space than local variables.

Here is my code:

**Local**

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    void dfs(int node, int parent, int& counter, vector<int>& low, vector<int>& id_to_rank, vector<vector<int>>& edges, vector<vector<int>>& ans){

        id_to_rank[node] = counter;
        low[node] = counter;
        counter++;

        for (const auto& e : edges[node]){
            if (parent == e) continue;

            if (id_to_rank[e] == -1){
                dfs(e, node, counter, low, id_to_rank, edges, ans);
            
                low[node] = min(low[node], low[e]);

                if (low[e] > id_to_rank[node]){
                    ans.push_back({e, node});
                }
            }else{
                low[node] = min(low[node], low[e]);
            }

        }

        return;
    }

    vector<vector<int>> criticalConnections(int n, vector<vector<int>>& connections) {
        vector<vector<int>> edges(n);
        vector<int> id_to_rank (n, -1);
        vector<int> low(n);

        vector<vector<int>> ans;
        int counter = 0;

        for (const auto& c : connections){
            edges[c[0]].push_back(c[1]);
            edges[c[1]].push_back(c[0]);

        }

        dfs(0, -1, counter, low, id_to_rank, edges, ans);

        return ans;
    }
};
```

**Instance**

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    int counter = 0;

    void dfs(int node, int parent, vector<int>& low, vector<int>& id_to_rank, vector<vector<int>>& edges){

        id_to_rank[node] = counter;
        low[node] = counter;
        counter++;

        for (const auto& e : edges[node]){
            if (parent == e) continue;

            if (id_to_rank[e] == -1){
                dfs(e, node, low, id_to_rank, edges);
            
                low[node] = min(low[node], low[e]);

                if (low[e] > id_to_rank[node]){
                    ans.push_back({e, node});
                }
            }else{
                low[node] = min(low[node], low[e]);
            }

        }

        return;
    }

    vector<vector<int>> criticalConnections(int n, vector<vector<int>>& connections) {
        vector<vector<int>> edges(n);
        vector<int> id_to_rank (n, -1);
        vector<int> low(n);

        for (const auto& c : connections){
            edges[c[0]].push_back(c[1]);
            edges[c[1]].push_back(c[0]);

        }

        dfs(0, -1, low, id_to_rank, edges);

        return ans;
    }
};
```

I have resubmitted both solution several times and the difference is constant(about 10% of memory). My guess is that maybe LeetCode use the same object on every testcase and thus the difference. But even so, I still have no idea what happened exactly.

Why using instance variables takes more memory compare to local variables in LeetCode?

(This is my first time posting question so if there are any rules that I did not follow please let me know)

Comment: Why don't you ask the leetcode people?

Comment: How do you call `dfs(e, node, counter, low, id_to_rank, edges, ans);` recursive with those exact arguments in both solutions, if one only supports 5 parameters and the other one 7?

Comment: @Joel updated that! Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @JesperJuhl Because I am not sure whether Leetcode is the problem or simply how C++ works

Answer (score 1):

`return ans` is returning a `COPY` of the member variable `ans` when called, so you require double the memory of that object,

```cpp
Solution sol; // has the vector
auto answer = sol.criticalConnections(...) // a copy is made
```

you can instead move the member out.

```cpp
return std::move(ans)


// the vector is moved into answer
auto answer = sol.criticalConnections(...) 
// after this line sol.ans is empty
```

as for the local variable version since the variable is not going to be used anywhere anymore, the compiler can do NRVO (copy elision) on it and not create the copy, and even if NRVO failed it should at least move it on its own.

unfortunately competitive coding sites only teach you competitive coding, they don't teach you coding, and they don't teach you C++, you are only going to learn c++ from [a proper c++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Both examples of `criticalConnections()` return a copy and LeetCode wont just use `auto answer& = sol.ans;` at the calling site just because of a different implementation of it, so how does that make a difference?

Comment: @Joel the second version moves the `ans` member into the return slot, which is returned as an `rvalue` which gets moved into `answer`, while the first version MUST copy the member variable into the return slot.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't quiet get it yet. Couldn't the first version be optimized by the compiler to move since it does not have `ans` as a member, but the second has to return a copy (if you don't move it yourself)?

Comment: @Joel exactly, i added that to the answer, either NRVO or a move are possible by the compiler.

Comment: `std::move` on a return value is usually a pessimisation.

Comment: @JesperJuhl unless that value is a member variable, which the compiler cannot copy-elide it, so the function should return a reference instead, and the caller should accept a reference, but this is LeetCode, and you cannot modify the caller or the function prototype.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Thanks for the answer! I did learn C++ in class and in some other textbooks. But after that, I felt like it was a little bit boring to keep learning from books and preferred some hands-on experience. That's why I chose leetcode to learn C++ along the way. Perhaps there is a more efficient/interesting way? Or like learning from textbooks is inevitable?

Comment: @frank880610 it depends on how much you are required to know, but consider value, reference and move semantics as well as ownership the very basics that you must know to write idiomatic c++, and try to apply your knowledge on real projects, almost all real world problems are not what you see on coding sites and instead require domain specific knowledge like desktop or networking or graphics or IPC or concurrency, and the real concern is safety and usability, not performance (so long as you are not too slow), which is where idiomatic c++ shines, unlike what coding sites are teaching.